# Symfony 3 one-to-many, get parent with all children if one child satisfy the codition

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have these two tables
[image]

I want to get all products(**with all the children**) that have at least one child with **log_id = 13**. Let's say I have the following rows in **eorder_product_config** table:

[image]

The function that retrieves the products looks like this:

```
public function getProducts($logId){

$q = $this
  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
  ->select('p', 'pc')
  ->where('pc.logisticStatus = :logId')
  ->setParameter('logId', $logId)
  ->getQuery();

  return $q->getResult();
}
```

This will get the product(id = 18) with only 2 children(id = 46,48) in the productConfigs collection and I want have all 5 children if there is at least one that has log_id = 13.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround using subqueries:

```
public function getProducts($logId){

  // search for configs that have log_id = 13
  $subQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('pp')
  ->select('DISTINCT pp.id')
  ->leftJoin('pp.productConfigs', 'ppc')
  ->leftJoin('ppc.logisticStatus', 'pls')
  ->where('ppc.logisticStatus = :logId');
  //->andWhere('ppc.id = p.id'); // used for EXIST query method

  // main query
  $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
  $q->select('p', 'pc');
  $q->leftJoin('p.productConfigs', 'pc')

  // inject subquery, check to see if current product is in
  // the subquery result
  $q->where($q->expr()->in('p.id', $subQuery->getDQL()));

  //$q->where($q->expr()->exists($subQuery->getDQL()))

  $q->setParameter('logId', $logId);

  return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

***I've seen that using the EXIST query does't work as it should that's why I choose the IN query. But in the raw sql query they both return same results.